# Debug Samsung Galaxy S3 Blank Screen Freezes

Tags: crashes, logging, system-freeze

my Samsung Galaxy S3 suffers from the Black/Blank screen freeze. The only remedy is to pull the battery to get the phone to respond again. I'm running Android 4.1.1 and I have done a factory reset. Now the symptoms are back. I would like to figure out a way to get the log of phone after I pull the battery so that I may be able identify which app is causing this issue. I have the Android SDK installed, but so far I can only get the current live log. How can I get a log history with time stamp?

Thanks,

Nick,

Comment: Did you have any luck with your problem?

Comment: I did a factory reset and I try to not download too many junk apps. It has only happened once since then. My phone has also been upgraded to 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several system monitors available you might want to give a try. Some of them log activities while running in the background, so no information is lost when the device has to be rebooted. While these might not *directly* point out the troublemaker, you could still see at what time the freeze happened, and which apps might have been active then -- so they should bring you at least closer to finding the culprit.

One of those monitor apps is [SystemPanel App / Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1) (it has a free trial version, but that does not log in the background but only allows for "live monitoring"). Some screenshots from the playstore for illustration:

[image: SystemPanel] [image: SystemPanel]
<sup>SystemPanel (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel))</sup>

An alternative would be [System Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw), which offers similar functionality.